# How to configure NCrunch so that it can build a Blazor project

Tags: blazor, ncrunch

When NCrunch (version 4.2.0.7) tries to build a Blazor project (version 3.0.0-preview9), it produces the following error:

> packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor.build\3.0.0-preview9.19465.2\targets\Blazor.MonoRuntime.targets (441, 5): The command "dotnet "C:\Users\Rodolfo.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor.mono\3.0.0-preview9.19462.2\build\netstandard1.0../../tools/illink/illink.dll" -l none --disable-opt unreachablebodies --verbose --strip-security true --exclude-feature com --exclude-feature sre -v false -c link -u link -b true -d *(... lots of files here...)* exited with code -532462766.

How can I get NCrunch to build Blazor projects?

Disclaimer: I'm writing this question after not finding a single answer online, including SO. I have already found the solution and intend to answer the question myself in order to - hopefully - help someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE (2023-09-04):** the Custom Build variables mentioned in the original post have changed.

1. Since Blazor General Availability, a variable IsWasmProject=false is required.
2. Since Visual Studio 17.7, a variable SelfContained=true is required (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/77036175/257372 for details)

---

Original post
**TL;DR**

1. Go to the NCrunch Configuration for the Blazor project.
2. Add a *Custom build property* named *BlazorLinkOnBuild* (as of 3.2.0-preview3, renamed to ***BlazorWebAssemblyEnableLinking***) with a value of *false*.

[image: NCrunch configuration for a project]
[image: NCrunch custom build property dialog]

---

**Full explanation**
... in case the details change.

In line 441 of the .targets file mentioned in the error message you will find the Exec command that causes the error:

```
<Exec Command="dotnet &quot;$(MonoLinkerPath)&quot; $(_BlazorLinkerAdditionalOptions) @(_BlazorFolderLookupPaths, ' ') -o &quot;$(BlazorIntermediateLinkerOutputPath)&quot; @(_BlazorAssemblyDescriptorFiles, ' ') @(_BlazorAssembliesToLink, ' ')"  />
```

This command is wrapped in the following target:

```
<Target
  Name="_LinkBlazorApplication"
  Condition="$(_BlazorShouldLinkApplicationAssemblies) != ''"
  Inputs="$(BlazorBuildLinkerInputsCache);
          @(IntermediateAssembly);
          @(_BlazorDependencyInput);
          @(BlazorLinkerDescriptor)"
  Outputs="$(BlazorIntermediateLinkerResultFilePath)"
>
```

Which means the Exec will only be executed if the _BlazorShouldLinkApplicationAssemblies property is not empty. Searching the .targets file for where this internal property is set, you will find this PropertyGroup (line 152):

```
<PropertyGroup Label="Build properties">
  <_BlazorShouldLinkApplicationAssemblies Condition="$(BlazorLinkOnBuild) == 'false'"></_BlazorShouldLinkApplicationAssemblies>
  <_BlazorShouldLinkApplicationAssemblies Condition="$(BlazorLinkOnBuild) == 'true'">true</_BlazorShouldLinkApplicationAssemblies>
  <_BlazorBuiltInBclLinkerDescriptor>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)BuiltInBclLinkerDescriptor.xml</_BlazorBuiltInBclLinkerDescriptor>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This is why setting the *BlazorLinkOnBuild* (as of 3.2.0-preview3, renamed to ***BlazorWebAssemblyEnableLinking***) to *false* allows NCrunch to build the project.