# Why am I getting The "ComputeBlazorBuildAssets" task was not given a value for the required parameter "DotNetJsVersion" when using NCrunch?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, blazor-webassembly, ncrunch

NCrunch is not able to compile these two projects:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNjZA.png)

Because of the same error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acBSF.png)

Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly.6_0.targets:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3e9X.png)

Visual Studio compiles with no errors.
Thank you.

.net version: 7.0.400
visual studio version: 17.7.2

I tried downloading the file from internet, but same results.
I tried restarting NCrunch, rebuilding solution, etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question was answered in the NCrunch forum, where official support is given.

The answer from Remco was:

> Try adding SelfContained=True for this project under your NCrunch 'Custom build properties' setting

This worked for me, as well as for the person who asked the original question.

Here's a screenshot of where this setting is located:
[image]

The full answer, which includes an explanation:

> The problem is caused by a recent change in VS that causes Blazor WASM
> project builds to break whenever they are built with
> SelfContained=false. From what I understand, this type of project
> isn't something that MS want to support without it being run with a
> self contained publishing mode.
>
> Under NCrunch, we force SelfContained=false because otherwise the
> build system slips an undeclared framework reference in that points to
> a platform target specific to this type of project. This causes
> problems with our ability to synchronise with grid nodes, as we need
> to know which packages are required by a project up-front before we
> try to build them on nodes.
>
> Could you please try adding SelfContained=True for this project under
> your NCrunch 'Custom build properties' setting?
>
> I hope that this will suppress the issue. If you're using distributed
> processing with this project, you'll need to perform a manual package
> restore on the remote nodes to make sure the required runtime pack is
> installed (the error will tip you off on this). If you're only running
> NCrunch locally, this shouldn't be an issue for you.
>
> I'm submitting a fix to NCrunch to force SelfContained=true for Blazor
> WASM projects in future released builds.

Answer (score 0):

(Supporting info for the above question because I do not have enough rep to Comment.)

1. It only started happening after upgrading Visual Studio to 17.7.2.
2. The issue occurs in both NCrunch 4.17.x.x and the latest 4.18.0.3.